# Why is a Bash variable empty inside of an if statement empty, but not outside of the if statement?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel7

```
cat > variables.sh << EOF1
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter your first name:"
read -e -i "Bob" FIRST_NAME
echo "Please enter your last name:"
read -e -i "Marley" LAST_NAME

echo "First name: $FIRST_NAME"
echo "Last name: $LAST_NAME"
if [[ "$FIRST_NAME" == "Bob" ]] ; then
echo "Last name: $LAST_NAME"
fi
EOF1
source ./variables.sh
```

Running the above results in:

```
First name: Bob
Last name: Marley
Last name:
```

For some reason, the LAST_NAME variable inside of the if statement is empty. But, if I call

```
echo "Last name: $LAST_NAME"
```

manually after the script has run I see:

```
Last name: Marley
```

So, I know the variable actually contains the last name.

It is acting as if the context inside of the if statement is different than the context outside of the if statement. Is that accurate?

What can I do to make this work the way I would expect ($LAST_NAME inside of the if statement contains the last name)?

I am testing this on RHEL7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `here-doc` as this:

```
cat > variables.sh <<-'EOF1'
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter your first name:"
read -e -i "Bob" FIRST_NAME
echo "Please enter your last name:"
read -e -i "Marley" LAST_NAME

echo "First name: $FIRST_NAME"
echo "Last name: $LAST_NAME"
if [[ "$FIRST_NAME" == "Bob" ]] ; then
echo "Last name: $LAST_NAME"
fi
EOF1
```

Using quotes in `EOF1` will prevent expansion of `$` variables in current shell.

As per `man bash`:

> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If
>          any part of word is **quoted**, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in  the  here-document  are  not
>          expanded.   If  word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and
>          arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \ is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the 1st echo statement worked for you and not the 2nd - both failed for me when I tried your script.  But you can probbably solve the problem if you make some slight changes.

As mentioned by **anubhava**, your variable values will be executed instantly and will not be passed into your destination script.  You need to escape them with a back slash.  Also, it is not necessary to use [[ and ]] in your if statement:  1 of each will do.  And a single equal sign (=) will do as well in the if statement.

So if you want your desired variables.sh script to be this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter your first name: "
read -e -i "Bob" FIRST_NAME
echo -n "Please enter your last name: "
read -e -i "Marley" LAST_NAME

echo "First name: $FIRST_NAME"
echo "Last name: $LAST_NAME"
if [ "$FIRST_NAME" = "Bob" ]; then
    echo "Last name: $LAST_NAME"
fi
```

You should make your initial script this:

```
cat > variables.sh << EOF1
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter your first name: "
read -e -i "Bob" FIRST_NAME
echo -n "Please enter your last name: "
read -e -i "Marley" LAST_NAME

echo "First name: \$FIRST_NAME"
echo "Last name: \$LAST_NAME"
if [ "\$FIRST_NAME" = "Bob" ]; then
    echo "Last name: \$LAST_NAME"
fi
EOF1
source ./variables.sh
```

And that should solve your problem.  Here's my output:

```
Please enter your first name: Bob
Please enter your last name: Marley
First name: Bob
Last name: Marley
Last name: Marley
```

NOTE:  I also added the "-n" option and a space inside the quote at the end of your echo statements.  This will suppress the newline and allow you to enter the answer on the same line as the prompt.

Comment: If you are not concerned with portability, there is no real benefit from using `[ ]`. `[[ ]]` keyword is faster and it has many functions `[ ]` doesn't.

Comment: On the other hand, `echo -n` is *really* unportable, since it can depend on the options `bash` was compiled with. Use `printf` instead, or in this case `read -p "Please enter...: " ...`.

Comment: I agree.  I knew the `echo -n` option is not always portable depending on the OS flavor.  But it is often available - I was just showing a simple way to clean up the prompting in many cases.  The `read -p` option is also not always available.

Comment: `read -p` should work in any version of bash; it will *not* work in any non-bash shell I'm aware of (and it means something completely different in zsh). `read -n`, on the other hand, isn't consistent even just under bash, even on the same OS. I learned this the hard way when OS X v10.5 came out with bash compiled with some option that changed `echo`, and I had to panic-rewrite a bunch of scripts. Been a strong believer in `printf` ever since.

Comment: We are in violent agreement - test the options in your flavor of Bash or use printf.  And we are drifting out of scope since the question was regarding Bash for RHEL7.